# UIButton steals UIView touch events

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uibutton, uitouch

I have a class which subclassed `UIView`. The class only have touch methods (to rotate view according to users touch).

From storyboard i added a view to my `ViewController`'s view and subclassed it with that custom class. The idea behind to receive its touch events, thats it.
In that View some `UIButton` is place covering the whole view.

Now requirement is when user clicks on button then its action should call else if he tries to rotate the view it should give spin rotation.

Every thing is working fine if i make user interaction of button to be false as obviously now Uiview is the `responder`. But this not what i want. I want button to be interact to action as usual and if user move his figure then rotate the view.

I achieve same thing with `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` but it is meant with 2 figures touch and i need to achieve same thing with single finger touch.

Any help and suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll have to override UIButton to alter its event response behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but want to know did you mean to say i need to override UIButton and handles its touch there. But how i will recognise that user wants to click the button or he wants to play with view with rotating having multiple buttons in it.

Comment: That's always the tricky part.  If the touch up is near the touch down, you can assume it was a tap.  What "close" means would be entirely your choice.